# Errors While Creating DNN Test Site On Local Machine

Tags: c#, iis, iis-7, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-5

I am trying to create test copy of a DNN live site on my local machine but only the home page of site is showing.  If we click on any menu item results in error "Page Not Found".  I am following this article for creating a test copy:

http://www.ifinity.com.au/2012/09/05/Creating_a_test_copy_of_your_DotNetNuke_website

After taking backup from FTP of the live site, I have files like:

```
Folders:

anon_ftp

cgi-bin

error_docs

httpdocs

httpsdocs

private

site1

static

subdomain

value_scripts

web_user

Files:

.Security
```

The main site is in `"httpdocs"` folders that are:

```
App_browser , App_code , App_data , desktopmodule, install , portals , provider default page Dnn icon web config.
```

I tried to host files under `"httpdocs"`  which I thought of as the main site and restore its database. By following steps from the link, I made a little in the database `"PortalAlias"` so that it can call the alias that I used.

Now when I run hosted test site it just open home page and when I click on the menu item it gives error `"404.0 Not Found"`

I reviewed the article once again and put in all files that I got from FTP. After that I configured it, enabled site "Directory Browsing" and also made httpdocs folder virtual directory.

Now calling link just showing me files on web browser and when i click httpdocs folder it gives error:

```
" It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS."
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: try this: Using windows explorer, open the web document root folder, right click and re-apply full permissions to using the same acount as the user on the IIS app pool.